# Task Scheduler's has a task with a Next Run Time in the past

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

[image]Creepy....

Anyone seen this before?

I can't think of anything I've done to cause this. Twice of the last two weeks, I've gone in to check on it, and I saw this.

Answer (score 6):

Always try manually refreshing the view of your scheduled tasks. Even if you just opened Task Scheduler fresh.

I've found sometimes it's necessary for me to right click and choose refresh to see up to date information, even if Task Scheduler snap in was closed when I logged onto the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I've just seen the same. 
I have a task that has successfully run every morning for a number of months, except for the last couple of days.
Looking at the Task Scheduler (which I had open), the Next Run Time is a couple of days ago.
If I close and re-open Task Scheduler the Next Run Time corrects.
Maybe there is a problem with keeping Task Scheduler open?